# ASP.net display TextBox controls using a loop

Tags: asp.net, loops

On an aspx page I have several of the TextBox control rows added like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <tr>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"</asp:TextBox>
         
         <asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
         
         <asp:DropDownList ID="dd2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         
         <asp:DropDownList ID="dd3" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </tr>
</asp:panel>
```

The above code works fine, however there are several of these rows, therefore I want to use a loop.

Assume these are 50 rows, I want to display these rows with a loop. I want to display only those rows where text fields are not empty.

```
<%
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {

        string txtBox = "txt" + i.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text)) {
            //display
        }
    }
 %>
```

In the above code, I am getting error at `txtBox.Text` because `txtBox` is a local variable.
I have also tried this:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)this.FindControl(txtBox);
```

This does not give error but it returns null.

So my question is that how can I display above controls with a loop instead of typing each control one by one.

Comment: @Austin thank you. Any chance that you could give a quick example of what you described? That would greatly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn’t matter if you have 3, or 30 here.

The simple matter is you want something to "repeat".

I would suggest a listview, or how about a "repeater" that repeats one chunk of markup over and list view over.

However, I have to think that some kind of data source is going to drive this data, and thus you want to think of solutions from a database point of view. And even when you list view don't have a database, you STILL want to think in terms of datasets, or data theory.

The second issue not addressed here is that combo box, or dropdown list.

I can't imagine that the values for those 50 rows is going to be typed in by hand. So, the list for the select values of course would also be from a data source. (Or at the very least some data set from code).

So, with above in mind, let's use a repeater, and "repeat" the one template.

Regardless, so say this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <div style="width:30%">
            <h3><%# Eval("hText") %></h3>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("TboxText") %>' >
            </asp:TextBox>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="dHotels" runat="server"
                style= "width:120px;margin-left:5px"                        
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="HotelName">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <hr/>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So, from above the key concept is you lay out the "one thing" you wish to repeat, and then simply feed the repeater a data list (or even a list of some class).

The data source for each row combo (dropdown list) was set one time, and we on the item data bound event, setup the choices for the combo box based on that data table.

So, code behind now can concentrate on building a data source, and not mess with markup.

So, then this code:

```
    DataTable rstHotels = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        // combo box data (same for each repeat)
        rstHotels = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");

        int NumRows = 7;   // number of repeat's

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("hText", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("TboxText", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < NumRows; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Item Text" + i.ToString();
            dr[1] = "TextBox " + i.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();   

    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DropDownList cboList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dHotels");
            cboList.DataSource = rstHotels;
            cboList.DataBind();
            cboList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select hotel", ""));
        }
    }
```

So, then your code becomes data operation, and "list" or "set" based operations, and you let the repeater control (or GridView, or ListView) handle the repeating of that one "row" of data or information that you send to that repeater "type" of control. While this example used a "Repeater" control, you have quite a few other choices.

The result of above is thus:

[image]

So, those from other code environments tend to use looping to add controls to a page, but as you can see the only looping code required for this SO posting was to create a "fake" data source.

Same goes for the dropdown list control and choices, they can be data source driven without requiring one to write or even use loops.

## Edit: User wants a "add row button"

This shows again why data operations should be just data operations, and not that of thinking in terms of markup.

Don't try and use the markup and UI as some kind of database store of data. Thus, to have a add button, we simple add to above a wee bit of code to persist the data the user enters.

So, say this markup with a add button:

```
<h3>My Hotel Ratings list</h3>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width:30%">
            <h3><%# Eval("hText") %></h3>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("TboxText") %>' >
            </asp:TextBox>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="dHotels" runat="server"
                style= "width:245px;margin-left:5px"                        
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="HotelName">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"
    OnClick="cmdAdd_Click" CssClass="btn"/>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Done"
    OnClick="cmdDone_Click" CssClass="btn"
    />
```

Now, our code is much the same, but we add one extra routine to persist the values into our "object". In this case I'm using a data table, but it could certainly be a class we define, and then we use a `List<My Class object>`.

So, our code is this:

```
    DataTable cboHotels = new DataTable(); // choices for combo box
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();    // repeating row data
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateTable();
            LoadData();
            Session["rstData"] = rstData;
        }
        else
        {
            rstData = (DataTable)Session["rstData"];
        }
    }

    void CreateTable()
    {
        rstData.Columns.Add("hText", typeof(string));
        rstData.Columns.Add("TboxText", typeof(string));
        rstData.Columns.Add("cboChoice", typeof(int));
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        // combo box data (same for each repeat)
        cboHotels =
            General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");

        Repeater1.DataSource = rstData;
        Repeater1.DataBind();   
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DropDownList cboList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dHotels");
            cboList.DataSource = cboHotels;
            cboList.DataBind();
            cboList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select hotel", "0"));
            DataRowView gRowData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            cboList.Text = gRowData["cboChoice"].ToString();
        }
    }

    void MyPersit()
    {
        // allows persiting of data
        // send repeater items back to rstData
        foreach (RepeaterItem rItem in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rstData.Rows[rItem.ItemIndex];
            OneRow["TboxText"] = ((TextBox)rItem.FindControl("txt")).Text;
            OneRow["cboChoice"] = ((DropDownList)rItem.FindControl("dHotels")).SelectedItem.Value;
        }
    }

    protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPersit(); // save any changes
        DataRow NewRow = rstData.NewRow();
        NewRow["hText"] = "Item " + (rstData.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        NewRow["cboChoice"] = 0;
        rstData.Rows.Add(NewRow);   
        LoadData(); 
    }

    protected void cmdDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // done, 
        MyPersit();

        // now process data
        foreach(DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        {
            Debug.Print(OneRow["TboxText"].ToString());
            Debug.Print(OneRow["cboChoice"].ToString());
            // etc. etc. etc.   
        }
    }
```

I mean, really, this data should be part of a database, since I can't imagine the user going to type in all that data, and then you not going to save such data, right?

However, even if this data not to be saved as a database? Note how thinking of this problem in terms of data operations, and ONLY using the markup and UI for display. The concept of the data operations should be thought of, and keep 100% separate from the markup and display part of your code.

The above results in this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am trying to do something different. In your image, you are displaying all Item Text fields at once, and what I want to do is that initially display just one field (ie. Item Text0) and below that add a button "Add more". If you press that button only then Item Text1 should appear.

Comment: Ok, that's a VERY different question!!! - but see my edit. Once again, you can see how well my advice in regards to thinking of data operations 100% separate from the display and UI part.  Note how we don't have to hard code the number of rows, and after all is said and done, we can send that rstData table back to the database in ONE operation. And of course by saving the data into a database, then going back to the page later to edit, since we again are thinking in terms of data, and not markup on the page? Then once again, we can go back and edit, and display data over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the id of the text box or other control by defining the variable.
txtBox is a variable and you treat it like a textbox id.
To solve this problem, I think you should build your controls entirely with the backend from the beginning. In this case, you can set their value in the loop. But to read their value, you can store their value in a cookie, for example, and then read them.
You can also use javascript to assign them values